# How do I insert a line into the head of all files in a directory?

Tags: vim, editing

I have multiple files in a directory. I want to insert the same line at the head of the files - something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#author: Alastor
```

How do I accomplish this? I am thinking vim might have something, but I am open to other options. Also can I do this recursively in nested folders?

Also, is there any way to get the name of the file and put it in there, ie:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#author: Alastor
#filename: asdf.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vim:

```
:args **/*.py
:argdo 0put="#!/usr/bin/python"|put="#author: Prashant"
```

(edit)

This one addresses your new requirement:

```
:args **/*.py
:argdo execute "let @q = '#!/usr/bin/python\n#author: Alastor\n#filename: " . expand('%') . "'|0put=@q"
```

This one uses a different, more intuitive, approach: macros!

```
:args **/*.py
qq
gg
O#!/usr/bin/python<CR>#author: Alastor<CR>#filename: <C-r>%
<Esc>
q
:argdo @q
```

No matter what method you use, you'll need to write the files to disk afterward:

```
:wa
```

Comment: Your answer is just as valid as the accepted answer, but I can only accept one answer, so I just picked one at random.

Comment: OK, no problem with me. But your question is tagged "vim" and the accepted answer doesn't involve Vim at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `find` along with `sed`

**Static Header**

```
find -type f -name '*.py' -exec sed -i '1i#!\/usr\/bin\/python\n#author: Prashant\n' {} \;
```

**Dynamic header with filename**

```
find -type f -name '*.py' -exec sh -c 'sed -i "1i#\!\/usr\/bin\/python\n#author: Prashant\n#filename: `basename $0`\n" $0' {} \;
```

**Short Description**

`find` command will find all ***.py** files recursively in present directory.

`-exec` option will pass each output of find command as an argument to following command. (here `sed`)

`sed` with `-i` option is used to insert desired content in found files at line #1 using `1i`.

`sh -c` with argument `$0` is used to print filename using `basename`